# python requests: show response in browser

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to open a page and get some data from it, using Requests and BeautifulSoup. How can I see the response of a `requests.post` in my browser as a page instead of the source code?

Answer (score 2):

For a fast solution I use:

```
print(response.text)
```

I copy that text from console and paste it to .txt file,
Then I rename the .txt file to .html file
In windows I do that with:

```
ren file.txt file.html
```

Now I open this file with a browser. You can drag and drop the file icon into an open browser.

You also can write the response directly to an html file with this pseudo-code:

```
with open('file.html',mode='w') as file:
    for line in response.text:
        file.write(line)
```

now you don't have to manually rename the file each time to an html, is already there ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about python GUI libraries like PyQt5 and instale it under your python libraries so that through QtWebEngineWidget and QWebView you can render your page to display it.

Comment: Your html page is parsed as an argument in side QWebView, finally create a window to display the page..